# Flask/SQLAlchemy Relationships

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I was reading about database relationships and I seem to be puzzled by this

below is the code of Miguel Grinberg in his [blog](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database)

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)
```

correct me if my understanding is wrong

```
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

the `posts` attribute is having a relationship to the `Post` model but  what does the `posts` attribute become? a field? what can it contain?
and what does `backref` mean? it's being defined as `author` but there is no `author` attribute in neither `Models`.

I looked into the docs and well as any newb would have it. I still don't quite get it.

so TL:DR

what does `posts` become?

what does `backref` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`posts` is an list that you can use as abstraction in SQLAlchemy to access. SQLAlchemy will translate it to the appropriate SQL query when you use it 
(it indicates a has-many relationship)

`backref` - hints SQLAlchemy that the property in `post` to indicate that it actually belongs to a specific `User`. In this case it is a mistake (look at the comments at the bottom of the blog) and should be `user`

Comment: so is it entire possible to do  `user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))` without having the `posts = db.relationships`?

how does `User.posts` know  which `posts` belong to whom?

Comment: You can, but you lose the power of SQLAlchemy (you are actually using plain SQL). You create a Post object. When you append in to user.posts, SQLAlchemy handles the indeices for you. recommended reading http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many